# Error in importing a tsv to hbase

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, csv

I created a table in [hbase](/questions/tagged/hbase) using:

```
create 'Province','ProvinceINFO'
```

Now, I want to import my data from a [tsv](/questions/tagged/tsv) file to it. My table in tsv have two columns: `ProvinceID` (as pk), `ProvinceName`

I am using the below code for import:

```
bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv '-Dimporttsv.separator=,'
-Dimporttsv.columns= HBASE_ROW_KEY, ProvinceINFO:ProvinceName Province /usr/data
/Province.csv
```

but it gives me this error:

```
ERROR: No columns specified. Please specify with -Dimporttsv.columns=...
Usage: importtsv -Dimporttsv.columns=a,b,c <tablename> <inputdir>

Imports the given input directory of TSV data into the specified table.

 The column names of the TSV data must be specified using the -Dimporttsv.columns 
option. This option takes the form of comma-separated column names, where each
column name is either a simple column family, or a columnfamily:qualifier. The special
column name HBASE_ROW_KEY is used to designate that this column should be used
as the row key for each imported record. You must specify exactly one column
to be t he row key, and you must specify a column name for every column that exists in 
the
input data. Another special columnHBASE_TS_KEY designates that this column should be
used as timestamp for each record. Unlike HBASE_ROW_KEY, HBASE_TS_KEY is optional.
You must specify at most one column as timestamp key for each imported record.
Record with invalid timestamps (blank, non-numeric) will be treated as bad record.
Note: if you use this option, then 'importtsv.timestamp' option will be ignored.

By default importtsv will load data directly into HBase. To instead generate
HFiles of data to prepare for a bulk data load, pass the option:
  -Dimporttsv.bulk.output=/path/for/output
Note: if you do not use this option, then the target table must already exist in HBase

Other options that may be specified with -D include:
-Dimporttsv.skip.bad.lines=false - fail if encountering an invalid line
'-Dimporttsv.separator=|' - eg separate on pipes instead of tabs
-Dimporttsv.timestamp=currentTimeAsLong - use the specified timestamp for the import
-Dimporttsv.mapper.class=my.Mapper - A user-defined Mapper to use instead of 
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TsvImporterMapper
-Dmapred.job.name=jobName - use the specified mapreduce job name for the import
For performance consider the following options:
-Dmapred.map.tasks.speculative.execution=false
-Dmapred.reduce.tasks.speculative.execution=false
```

Comment: Have you already tried to remove the spaces after the = and commas in -Dimporttsv.columns option?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe also try wrapping column into a string, i.e.

```
bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv -Dimporttsv.separator=','
-Dimporttsv.columns="HBASE_ROW_KEY, ProvinceINFO:ProvinceName" Province /usr/data
/Province.csv
```

Comment: This is duplicated answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/23264841/3294286 but it is impossible to edit that answer just to add a couple of " characters, so I guess it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like:

```
bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv -Dimporttsv.separator=','
-Dimporttsv.columns= HBASE_ROW_KEY, ProvinceINFO:ProvinceName Province /usr/data
/Province.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the spaces in `-Dimporttsv.columns=a,b,c`.